# ExtJS4 window header issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are using ExtJS4 in our application.But we are facing problem with window header.We need to remove header or decrease height using CSS from window but not the minimize tool.Please have a look into the image.You will find highlight portion on image that portion we need to remove.

[image]

CSS for that portion:

```
    <div id="component-1248" 
class="x-component x-component-default x-box-item" 
    role="presentation" 
style="margin: 0pt; width: 374px; height: 15px; left: 1px; top: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

My doubt is whether we can remove or decrease the height of the header (hightlight portion) but not the minimize tool.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly if you decrease the height of the header, you will not be able to decrease it below the height of the minimize icon. What you could do is set `background: none` on the header element, which would eliminate the visual look of a "height" on the title.

Comment: yeah we can do that but i need to remove height of that header.In ExtJS3 we have done but now it is not accepting the CSS to remove the height.